# How to run R scripts on servers without X11

Tags: linux, r, x11

I want to run R scripts and save the plots using `png()`. X11 is not supported on the Unix servers and I get the following error message:

```
Error in X11(paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width, g$height, pointsize,  : 
  unable to start device PNG
Calls: png
In addition: Warning message:
In png("test.png", width = 900, height = 400) :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
Execution halted
```

Setting environment variables

```
Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0.0")
```

or

```
Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0")
```

in the R scripts didn't solve the problem.

This code example produces the error above:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# Some data
df = data.frame(x = c(1.2,5,3,5.3,2,9,4,6,8,0), y = c(1.5,6,2.5,5.1,2.3,8.7,4.1,6,8,0))


# Base plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 8), expand = c(0,0)) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 8), expand = c(0,0)) +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, formula=y~x, aes(colour="2"), show_guide=TRUE, fill=NA, size=1.2) +
   geom_vline(xintercept = 3) + geom_vline(xintercept = 7) +
   opts(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,4,1), "lines"))

# Create the text Grobs
Text1 = textGrob("Part 1")
Text2 = textGrob("Part 2")
Text3 = textGrob("Part 3")

# Add the annotations
# Segment 1
p1 = p +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 0, xmax = 0, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -.75) +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 0, xmax = 3, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -1) +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 3, xmax = 3, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -.75) +
     annotation_custom(grob = Text1,  xmin = 0, xmax = 3, ymin = -1.25, 
ymax = -1.25)

# Segment 2
p1 = p1 +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 3, xmax = 7, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -1) +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 7, xmax = 7, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -.75) +
     annotation_custom(grob = Text2,   xmin = 3, xmax = 7, ymin = -1.25, 
ymax = -1.25)

# Segment 3
p1 = p1 +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 7, xmax = 8, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -1) +
     annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 8, xmax = 8, ymin = 
-1, ymax = -.75) +
     annotation_custom(grob = Text3,  xmin = 7, xmax = 8, ymin = -1.25, 
ymax = -1.25)

png("test.png", width=900, height=400)

# Code to override clipping
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)

dev.off()
```

The outcome of `capabilities()` is:

```
   jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE 

  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
    TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
```

I am running the scripts via a sun grid engine.

Comment: Was the R even compiled with X11 support? Check out `capabilities()` on the server. IIRC you can have an X virtual framebuffer instead of X which will allow this to work, but that assumes that the X  virtual framebuffer package/software is installed on the server (on Linux, Fedora I can install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb for this purpose). If that fails, find a graphics device that is supported by your server, plot to that and retrieve the file and then convert to PNG on your local system

Comment: How are you connected to the server?  I think `ssh` has an option to turn on or off X11 tunneling.

Comment: jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE 
  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
    TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE

Comment: What version of R are you on? If I unset DISPLAY and run R, I can do: png(file="foo.png");plot(1:10);dev.off() and get a PNG even though I can't talk to my X11 server (which I verify because X11() fails). I believe png uses cairo if there's no X11 if you have cairo in your capabilities. Which I don't think you do. Get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this once before -- can cannot make a program which expects X11 to certainly forget about it, but you can use the virtual framebuffer to 'pretend' X11 is present.

So see [this older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710853/how-to-run-r-on-a-server-without-x11-and-avoid-broken-dependencies) for details and an example.

Answer (score 41):

if you are using R 3.0, try `options(bitmapType='cairo')`
it worked for me

Comment: Where did you place that? Before or after the png() call, or somewhere else?

Comment: I placed it before png() call and once is enough for all png() calls. Sorry for delayed answer

Comment: Hi, this is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I had to add `options(bitmapType='cairo')` to my `~/.Rprofile`

Comment: magnificent, this worked also for me on our cluster. Thanks a lot