# How should I solve "unable to open connection to X11 display" this problem? At Linux Rstudio

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, rstudio-server

When I use the plot method, then result is Error....

The problem is

> Rstudio GD(), unable to open connection to X11 display ''.

So, When I entered `capabilities()` at Rstudio (Linux), then results are as follows.

```
jpeg   png      tiff ....      X11..... cairo
FALSE FALSE     FALSE ....     FALSE     FALSE
```

I want to change FALSE to TRUE....

So.. How can I solve this problem?

I was searching google.... but I don't satisfied about this problem.

Comment: What Linux distro are you running?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999983/r-unable-to-start-device-png-capabilities-has-true-for-png

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu14.04.

Comment: Hm.. The site problem is jpeg, png, tiff all TRUE... But My problem is ALL FALSE...

Comment: You might try installing `libpango1.0-dev` (i.e. `sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev` from the terminal). You may also have to reinstall RStudio afterward. See [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200642948-RStudio-Server-unable-to-open-connection-to-X11-display) for a related discussion.

Comment: Wow Thank you I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting all the `capabilities()` (at least for mac os x Mojave) is to do it through homebrew.

First you should uninstall R and Cairo as well (should you have it installed).
Then you need to install Xquartz and finally re-install R.

Please refer to the following post for a detailed walk through.

https://luispuerto.net/blog/2018/05/11/installing-r-with-homebrew-with-all-the-capabilities/