# saving png/jpeg when X11 is not available

Tags: r, png, jpeg

I am using a R package that renders the png images.
As I am running the command below in a script, I would like to avoid the error below and still be able to save the images.
How shall I do it ?

```
> ChIPQCreport(SAMPLE, 
+              reportName = paste(ENTRY, "ChIPQC", sep="."), 
+              reportFolder = paste(ENTRY, "ChIPQCreport", sep="."))
Saving 7 x 7 in image
Error in png_dev(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : X11 is not available
```

Comment: Try `options(bitmapType='cairo')`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067751/how-to-run-r-scripts-on-servers-without-x11

Comment: Thank you, yes, I did, although the png files are not saved on the disk anymore, but skipped. In the output folder, "rmD.bam.ChIPQCreport" there are only text, and not images.

Comment: Seems not doable see https://github.com/shengqh/ChIPQC/issues/6