# generate png with R

Tags: r, dependencies, png, x11

I Installed R-3.0.2 from source on Ubuntu Server 11.10 (sudo ./configure, sudo make) and want to be able to generate png-files (not view them) on the server. When i try to run "png();" in R I get the following Error:

> Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
>     unable to start device PNG
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In png() : unable to open connection to X11 display ''

Tthe following dependencies are installed:

> libpng12-dev (1.2.46)
>   java (1.6.0_27)
>   xorg-dev (1:7.6+7ubuntu7.1)
>   libcairo-dev (1.10.2-6ubuntu3)...
>   
>   Update:
>   libx11-dev (2:1.4.4-2ubuntu1)
>   libxt-dev (1:1.1.1-2)

(could be I forgot some)

Running capabilities(); in R give the following:

> jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets
>       TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
>     libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo
>       TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE

So png is ok, but X11 seems to be missing, any idea's what I need to install/do to get png capability working in R (to get X11 up and running?) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run R on a server without X11, and avoid broken dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710853/how-to-run-r-on-a-server-without-x11-and-avoid-broken-dependencies)

Comment: I don't mind installing X11, I just don't now how. Also I need to be able to run the 'R' command just like that and not via some additional software (like the xvfb-run suggested in that post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question thanks to comments from @Spacedman

Turned out I still needed to install the 'libpango1.0-dev' package. "capabilities('X11');" still gives FALSE but "png();" no longer gives errors, so my problem is fixed. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the relevant X11 development library packages on your system, and recompile R so it says `TRUE` in the X11 capabilities.

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxt-dev
```

or maybe just the `xorg-dev` metapackage:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

might be enough. Then run the configure step of the install until it says it has got X11 capabilities. It should output it on screen during the configure step, so you don't need to churn through a compile to find out.

Note that `png` support doesn't need a connection to a working X server anymore so anything you read about needing virtual X server process (via xvfb) on headless servers does not apply.

Comment: All those packages are already installed (see my updated question for versions). When I run ./configure I get this:  
Interfaces supported:      X11  
  External libraries:        readline  
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, NLS, cairo  
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling  
  
However, X11 capability is still FALSE

Comment: Check your config log file to see what it can't find.

Comment: Might pango be the problem? How can install a newer version? I found this in the config log: checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo and pango... no
checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo... yes
checking whether cairo is >= 1.2 and works... yes