# Compile R with Cairo support without X11

Tags: r, installation, cairo

I'm trying to compile R 3.1.1 from source with cairo support enabled. I want this because I'm trying to run R on a server which does not have a graphical environment (hence no X11), but still output PNG's.

I tried to configure R with

```
./configure --with-x=no --with-cairo=yes --with-libpng=yes --enable-R-shlib --prefix=$HOME
```

Doing this produces an R binary with no png or cairo support (as evidenced by `capabilities()`). In `config.log`, there is the following.

```
configure:31563: checking for X 
configure:31749: result: disabled
configure:32420: result: using X11 ... no
configure:32530: checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo and pango 
configure:32542: result: yes
configure:32576: checking whether cairo including pango is >= 1.2 and works 
configure:32599: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -g -O2 -fpic  -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -I/home/rmccloskey/include/pango-1.0 -I/home/rmccloskey/include/cairo -I/home/rmccl
oskey/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/rmccloskey/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/home/rmccloskey/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/rmccloskey/include/freetype2 -I/home/rmc
closkey/include/libpng16   -L/usr/local/lib64 conftest.c -lrt -ldl -lm  -L/home/rmccloskey/lib -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpng16 -lz -lcairo   >
&5
conftest.c:232:24: fatal error: cairo-xlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cairo-xlib.h>
                        ^     
compilation terminated.
```

As you can see, configure knows about cairo and pango, and it also knows that I'm not using X11. But it still tries to compile a file requiring `cairo-xlib.h`? What can I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most narrow sense, Cairo appears to require x11 headers.

In a wider sense, look into the various answers detailing use of the `xvfb` virtual x11 server -- they allow you headless use.

Also, you could try building without x11, png, cairo -- and then use one of the two cairo packages from CRAN to create graphs. In Debian/Ubuntu we also have at least the [cairoDevice](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=cairoDevice) package pre-build for you.

Comment: Cairo doesn't require X11 headers. I successfully built Cairo without X11 headers. The issue is that, for some reason, R is requiring Cairo to have been built with Xlib support, despite the ``--with-x=no`` flag to configure.

Comment: There is no point in complaining to me about it. If you think the world needs this, prepare a patch and send it to R Core -- else there may be a remaining dependency on x11 font metrics or something like it. I showed you several ways in which you can create graphs even when you work on a headless machine, so I consider the whole point mostly moot. But your mileage may of course vary.

Comment: Thanks. I apologise, I wasn't complaining, but rather I thought you misunderstood my question. Unfortunately I'm running somebody else's code so other packages aren't an option. I guess I'll look into xvfb, thanks.

Comment: No worries, and yes, xvfb should help you. I think I answered a few questions about it on here over the years too, see eg [this old one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1710952/143305). You want to wrap your script in `xvfb-run`.

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to make this work with CentOS-6.5 and R-3.1.2. I had to yum install cairo and pango first. Here is my configure command:

./configure --with-recommended-packages=no --without-x --with-cairo --with-libpng --with-libtiff --with-jpeglib --enable-R-shlib

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact some problem. I solved this by using the very hackish way below.

In the R.x.y.z src directory, edit the configure file. There is the line:

```
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
```

I simply removed this line. And then run this file and make. Everything works for me. My cairo is compiled with out x11 support. Because I am on a shared RHEL6 box. I do everything without root. The purpose I do this is to make R work with Jupyter notebook. In addition to this, I also need to add `options(bitmapType='cairo')` in `$HOME/.Rprofile`. This [Link](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/388) is very helpful.

By doing all these hacks, everything works for me now. :)