# Error with X11 on R

Tags: r

I tried the following command in `RStudio` version `Version 0.99.441` in `Linux` system:

```
 X11(width=800,height=600,pointsize=12)
```

But it gives me the error:

```
No protocol specified
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
 unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In X11(width = 800, height = 600, pointsize = 12) :
 unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

I am not able to find out the problem here.

**ADDITION**

```
capabilities()
```

It gives the following output:

```
jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Comment: Please provide the details as to what system you're trying to run it on.

Comment: `width` and `height` are in inches. You try to open a window of  20.32m x 15.24m.

Comment: I am trying to do this on `linux` using `RStudio`.

Comment: @Pascal Same error, when i tried `X11(width=8, height=6, pointsize=12)`.

Comment: `X11(width=8, height=6, pointsize=12)` works for me, inside and outside RStudio. What is the output of `capabilities()`? Please post the output in your question.

Comment: @Pascal `x11()` is also showing the same problem.

Comment: @Pascal yes I noticed the changes and added the information.

Comment: You don't have capability for `X11()`. Try with `windows()`.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire Are you running linux as your primary system or are connected to a shell account or VM?

Comment: @JakubKania connected to a Shell account.

Comment: @Pascal the function `windows` return the error `unidentified function`.

Comment: @Pascal funciton `X11` is working on `r` on the same system. The only problem is with `RStudio`.

Comment: I don't understand why you need `X11()` on RStudio.

Comment: to fix the width and length of the plot without resizing with clipboard. @Pascal

Answer (score 0):

As per [r-manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/x11.html):

> X11 starts a graphics device driver for the X Window System (version
>   11). This can only be done on machines/accounts that have access to an
>   X server.

That means you have to have a 'nix system that has a support for graphics devices. Since you're running a shell account you're connected to a server that doesn't have any or you don't have the privileges.

In this situation you can either contact the admin of your server and ask about installing the xvfb ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710952/2115135)). Or you can run R on a virtual machine on your own computer.