# How to launch an R session with rpy2 that will use virtual framebuffer X11 server

Tags: r, linux, python-2.7, rpy2, xvfb

I'm running `R` (3.2.2) on a Debian Jessie VPS thanks to `rpy2` (2.6.1) through `Python` (2.7.10).

I have a `Flask` (0.10.1) application launching `R` via `rpy2` and then loading `R` package `devEMF` (2.0.0) to plot various graphics. The aim is to save vector images created thanks to `devEMF`.

My sample code is:

```
robjects.r(u'''
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(qgraph))
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(devEMF))

    emf(file =  "''' + pathToSaveGraphEmf + '''", bg = "white", width = 6.25, height = 5.21)
    attach(mtcars)
    plot(wt,mpg)
    dev.off()
''')
```

And I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106:   UserWarning: Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  Can't open connection to X server to read font metric information.

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: In addition:
  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Warning message:

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: no DISPLAY variable so Tk is not available

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
[2016-01-21 20:03:18 +0000] [21430] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_classy.py", line 200, in proxy
    response = view(**request.view_args)
  File "/routines/routine2.py", line 124, in keyDriverAnalysis
    myCorrelationMatrix, rowName, colName = r2.getCorrelationGraph(myCorrelationMethod, myPreparedData, myGroupUserInput, myDependentVariable, myIndependentVariable, myPathToSaveGraph)
  File "../graph.py", line 194, in getCorrelationGraph
    ''')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 317, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
RRuntimeError: Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  Can't open connection to X server to read font metric information.
```

devEMF needs [X11 and Xft](https://github.com/cran/devEMF/blob/master/src/fontmetrics.h) (line 35), when not running on `OSX` or `Windows`, so I installed it. But now it is unable to connect to the X server. Certainly because the VPS has no GUI feature.

Hopefully I found this very helping [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710853/how-to-run-r-on-a-server-without-x11-and-avoid-broken-dependencies), and I understood that I should use virtual framebuffer `X11` server.

I tried the advice from the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710853/how-to-run-r-on-a-server-without-x11-and-avoid-broken-dependencies) in a command line `R` session, and it worked ! (Now it outputs an empty file, but it was fully working two minutes ago. (I had downloaded the file, inserted is in an .xls file and my graph was *openable* and *ungroupable*.))

But now I have to make it work within `rpy2`.

I tried the second answer in the previously cited [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710853/how-to-run-r-on-a-server-without-x11-and-avoid-broken-dependencies), but it doesn't work because it gives a trick when `X11` is problematic when loading but not needed then.

I think where I am now is: how do I launch an `R` session thanks to `rpy2` that will use `virtual framebuffer X11 server` ?

EDIT0:

I think I found something useful [here](https://www.labkey.org/home/Documentation/wiki-page.view?name=configVirtualFrame). It explains how to configure a Virtual Frame Buffer on headless unix servers.

EDIT1:

Eventually, what I have done:

- Launch `xvfb` thanks to the command from the main environment, and bind it to the desired screen (`1`) (I don't reminder where I found this precise line, but well it can be analyzed thanks to the [xvfb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xvfb-run.1.html) documentation):

  ```
  Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
  ```
- Attach the tmux session, and export the `DISPLAY` environment variable linked to the correct screen (`1`):

  ```
  export DISPLAY=:1
  ```

And it works !

Important note: the environment variable should be set inside the session.

Also: I don't have the "launch at boot time" problem mentioned in the link from EDIT0, probably because I am on a VPS (the `xvfb-run` folder is still in `tmp` and it seems to run because I can plot and save in .emf ;-) )

Comment: It's indeed going to be either start `Xvfb` as you point it out in your edit,  or `xvfb-run python`. At least that's what I'd guess.

Comment: I didn't think about `xvfb-run python` ! I use `gunicorn`, I guess I could do `xvfb-run gunicorn`, but I wonder if it would have a wrong impact on some other features of the app. Otherwise, I run the `Flask` application in a `tmux` session which is never killed, so i think I can start `Xvfb` only once in this session, and this might be the best solution. I'll try and give feedback about this.