# X11 is not available in R

Tags: r, x11

**Problem**

I'm following along some code and get an error related to X11. To recreate my error, I ran x11() and got the following:

```
> x11()
Error in x11() : X11 is not available
```

I have definitely plotted things in R that loaded the XQuartz program to display.

**What I tried**

- I did `?x11()` and saw that it is from the `{grDevices}` package. I loaded that library, tried again, but got the same error. I read that X11 is related to XQuartz.
- I re-installed XQuartz 2.7.8. I have R 3.2.3 and am running OSX El Capitan version 10.11.4 (15E65). I restarted twice after re-installing.
- `install.packages("Cairo")`

  `> x11( width=3, height=3) Error in x11(width = 3, height = 3) : X11 is not available`

  `> Sys.getenv("DISPLAY") [1] "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.F1bsaVCA43/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"`

  `> capabilities() jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp  TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE  sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem  TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE  cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl  TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE`

**Google researching**

I Googled using my error message and searched through the first two pages of my results but didn't find any solutions that worked. Based on my perusal of solutions, I provided my system information above since it seems to be relevant somehow. Any ideas/solutions/new leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The XQuartz package is the Mac X11 and your version is the current one. I'm wondering if you need to reboot after installation although I don't claim to know that. (And it might not hurt to repair permissions.)  On my Mac (running 3.3.0 on El Cap) I need to set width and height (in inches, not pixels or points);

```
 x11( width=3, height=3)
```

What do you get with:

```
Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")
```

Might be something along the lines of:

```
"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.KImNTikz8K/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"
```

Also run:

```
capabilities()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not sure how to repair permissions. I followed your suggestions and edited my post to include the additional information to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and installing R separately from Rstudio fixed it. You can download it from [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/) and verify x11 is working using x11()

Comment: Yup, originally I tried to install R with Homebrew and had this issue. Then I uninstalled it and downloaded the R installer directly from the website and it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a local X server, so get [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) because you are on MacOS.

If you were on Ubuntu you could install the virtual framebuffer X11 server like [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710952/535203):

```
apt-get install xvfb xauth xfonts-base
```

Now that you have X virtual framebuffer installed, you can start a new instance like [said here](https://gist.github.com/jterrace/2911875):

```
Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1960x2000x24 &
```

Then if your R is compiled with `with-x` configuration option (enabled by default), you should have X11 capability, and you just have to declare this in R:

```
Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0")
```

Comment: OP is running MacOS "am running OSX El Capitan version 10.11.4", so your answer's unlikely to be useful to them

Comment: I was with the same problem on my R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) and after performing the very first instruction of this post (downloading and install XQuartz-2.7.11.dmg the problem was solved out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the R from cran (not Homebrew). After so doing the `X11` will show up in `capabilities()` :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling R in R 4.2.2 I realized that compiling normally would not build it with x11 capability. You have to specify it during `./configure` by adding `--with-x=yes`.