# Forwarding X11 from cluster to Mac OS Sierra (Using R)

Tags: r, linux, macos, cluster-computing

I'm trying to forward X11 from a university's cluster to my local mac, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

My goal is to display graphics from an R program run on the cluster.

I installed latest version of XQuartz on my mac.
I also this on my local mac:

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true
```

Next, I logged into the cluster trying either -X or -Y to enable remote X11 display.

```html
-bash-4.2$ R

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> library(Seurat)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: cowplot

Attaching package: â

The following object is masked from â:

    ggsave

Loading required package: Matrix
seq> setwd("/home/CAM/anesta/LiLab2/allCells/data/")
> cdS <- readRDS("Diencephalon_merged.rds")
FeaturePlot(cdS, "Gbx2")
> FeaturePlot(cdS, "Gbx2")
Error in (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
  X11 module cannot be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to load shared object '/isg/shared/apps/R/3.4.1/lib64/R/modules//R_X11.so':
  libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
echo -bash-4.2$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? R shouldn't be looking for a local X11 install because it the commands are being forwarded to my local mac, correct? Do I need X11 installed on the cluster?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Did you start XQuartz on your Mac first - it doesn't always seem to start automagically. Also, try logging into the cluster and just running `xclock` so we can rule out problems within `R`.

Comment: This post may help you narrow the problem down: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819334/x11-is-not-available-in-r

Comment: So, running xclock sends back a command not found error when run on the cluster. Additionally, you can see the results of echo $DISPLAY from the cluster is localhost:10.0. And yes, XQuartz was started first and NEVER starts automatically when I login into cluster, but will start when I make an X11 call in terminal locally.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503005/2836621