# is there any way to hide port number while login with ssh that need custom port number

Tags: bash, ssh, alias

I want to login to my server that has custom ssh port like -

```
ssh -p <my server port number> root@example.com
```

Now I want such short command (something like alias) that I don't need to input that port number again and again. Like -

```
ssh my-short-code
```

Is it possible? If yes any hint are welcome.

Comment: i want "ssh my-short-code" but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Create once an alias or a function in your `~/.bashrc` or put those two lines to `~/.ssh/config`: `Host example.com` and `port <my server port number>`. Then you can use `ssh example.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `ssh` config file - mine is in `$HOME/.ssh/config`, and add the following:

```
Host example
HostName example.com
User root
Port 2229
```

Then you can just do:

```
ssh example
```

If you want to be able to run X11 applications (e.g. `xclock` or `xterm` or any graphical software development tools) on the remote machine, but display the graphics locally, you can forward X11 by adding the following 2 lines after the ones shown above:

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

---

In response to your further question in the comments. Yes, you can just keep adding as many additional servers as you like, with different ports, usernames, keep-alive intervals for each:

```
Host example
HostName example.com
User root
Port 2229

Host sercon
HostName sercon.onlinehome-server.info
User u8566723
Port 378
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

You can also put a generic entry at the start with settings you want for most servers, and then override them later on individual servers:

```
Host *
Username mark
ServerAliveInterval 10

Host XYZ
<specific stuff for this host>

Host <ABC>
<specific stuff for this host>
```

To get further information, use this in Terminal:

```
man ssh_config
```

---

If you happen to be on a Mac under `macOS/OSX` and you want X11 forwarding to work with XQuartz, put these 3 lines at the top of the file:

```
Host *
# https://serverfault.com/a/859370/235272
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Comment: if i have multiple host (mean multiple server) with different port, is it supported? and how it managed?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question, please have another look.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly that, but you can do something very similar. In your `.bashrc` add this line:

```
export myshortcode='-p <my server port number> root@example.com'
```

Now you execute the command loke this:

```
ssh $myshortcode
```

Or you add an alias like

```
alias ssh_port='ssh -p <my server port number> root@example.com'
```

Comment: `export` can be omitted.