# how to see the processed image without imshow?

Tags: python, opencv, networking, beagleboard

I'm using beagleboard without GUI so I can't use cv2.imshow.
how can I see the processed image ? like send data to others computer in local network or something.

Comment: What OS are the other computers using? What OS is the BeagleBone running? Do you `ssh` into your BeagleBone to run your OpenCV program?

Comment: my laptop using mac os . BeagleBone using debian.
yes, I ssh into my BeagleBone to run program.

Answer (score 3):

I would install **XQuartz** on your Mac so that you have an X11 server, then when you login to to your BeagleBone via `ssh`, use `ssh -Y user@beaglebone` and then `imshow()` will show up on your Mac's screen.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503005/2836621) to see how to automate that with your `ssh` config file.

Test that XQuartz is set up correctly on your Mac first by running `xeyes` or `xclock` from the Terminal. When that works, try `ssh`ing into your BeagleBone and running `xeyes` or `xclock` there. Once that works, try with OpenCV `imshow()`.

---

Alternatively, share a directory on your BeagleBone with the Mac via NFS or Samba, and save your images (from your OpenCV code) on disk in that directory on your BeagleBone. Then mount that directory from the Mac (using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> in the Finder) and use `Preview` or `QuickLook` to view the files.

QuickLook is when you tap once briefly on a file in Finder with the mouse to select it, then press <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to quicklook at the file and once more to close QuickLook.