# How to install X11 in R on Windows 10

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to install X11 since if I look for it

```
capabilities()
 jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets 
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE
libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU
 TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
long.double     libcurl 
TRUE        TRUE
```

It gives me false.

I recently update both R and RStudio.

My `R.version`

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Comment: what s your version of R? ( command   "    R.version.  ")

Comment: I found this on stackoverflow, I hope it can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819334/x11-is-not-available-in-r

Comment: I re-edit my question with the information you asked for. Furthermore, I already found this question  stackoverflow.com/questions/36819334/x11-is-not-available-in-r but unfortunately is for MacOS system while I have WIndows 10.