# Cannot get to install ggplot2 from within RStudio or R console

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm running R v3.2.0 with RStudio as well. The machine I'm running on has no internet access and therefore I'm having to download and install packages locally. I am trying to install ggplot2 which requires lots of dependecies (with their own dependencies) to be downloaded and installed. I have arrived at the point where most of them have been installed. However, I still get the following when I try:

```
> install.packages("~/R_packages/ggplot2_2.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
No protocol specified
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : couldn't connect to display ":0"
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/R/library/scales/libs/scales.so':
  /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/R/library/scales/libs/scales.so: invalid ELF header
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/R/library/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/oracle/R_packages/ggplot2_2.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Edit:

```
Oracle Distribution of R version 3.2.0  (--)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Oracle Linux Server 6.7 

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8          
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8        LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8       
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8      LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dplyr_0.4.2         stringi_0.4-1       nnet_7.3-9          randomForest_4.6-10 ROracle_1.2-1      
 [6] DBI_0.3.1           rpart_4.1-9         ORCH_2.5.1          ORCHstats_2.5.1     ORCHcore_2.5.1     
[11] rJava_0.9-7         OREstats_1.5        MASS_7.3-40         OREbase_1.5         OREcommon_1.5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.2    png_0.1-7      assertthat_0.1 R6_2.0.1       grid_3.2.0     OREembed_1.5   magrittr_1.5  
[8] tools_3.2.0    parallel_3.2.0
```

Edit 2:

```
library(ggplot2)
No protocol specified

Attaching package: ‘ggplot2’

The following object is masked from ‘package:randomForest’:

    margin

Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) : couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

Comment: Your platform (and all of `sessionInfo()`) might be helpful. (i.e. something more specific than "linux").

Comment: Maybe this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710853

Comment: @joran just updated the question with info from sessionInfo()

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the `scales` package (which is a dependency). Have you tried installing that explicitly first?

Comment: MrFlick I just installed scales I'm getting the following warning messages above: look at the last Edit